# iOS 8 and App Previews

Tags: ios, app-store, ios8, app-store-connect

As you may now, `Apple` sent an email to developers last week to introduce new features in `iTunes Connect`, such as the `App Previews`. In this email it was said that:

> iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite are required to capture an App Preview video.

And in the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH19-SW31), the `App Preview` is stated as optional.

So... does that mean that the `App Preview` is only required if submitting an app version targeting iOS 8? Or does it just mean that you must have iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite to create the `App Preview`? Could I submit a new version of my app still targeting iOS 7 with no `App Preview`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no requirement to provide app previews.

It means if you wish to provide the optional app reviews, that you need iOS 8 and Yosemite to create the app preview.

Comment: I have wasted an entire week trying to doctor a preview video. The language on their site plays games on you to think it's a requirement . Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

It means that you must have iOS 8 and Yosemite in order to create the video.

Yosemite combined with iOS 8 will allow you to register directly from your iPhone and upload the video as optional app preview.